# Standard result for $\log(x)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

$$\sum_{1\leq m\leq x/d}\frac{1}{m}=\log(\frac{x}{d})+O(1)$$

I read this result in lecture papers I was going through and can't find anything about its origin.

Is there a standard summation result for $\log(x)$ in terms of a summation or $\sum_{k=1}^x\frac{1}{m}$ in terms of $\log(x)$

Can someone link me to information about this identity if possible, thanks.

Comment: See ['integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Integral_test) and [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may look at it this way:
$$\sum_{1\leq m\leq x/d}\frac{1}{m}\approx\int_1^{\frac{x}{d}}\frac1{m}dm=\log(m)|_1^{x/d} = \log(\frac{x}{d})$$

The $O(1)$ comes from residuals when converting sum to integer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Rate_of_divergence) is what you are looking for.